# Best practices to speed up Polymer Dart?

Tags: php, mysql, dart, dart-polymer, polymer

I am currently writing a web app using Dart-Polymer, PHP, and MySQL. My biggest concern is speed. Some of this will be server side that can't be helped. The part I wonder though is, can polymer dart elements be combined into one larger packages to prevent the need to start multiple http requests to receive them?

Also, are there any other good practices to optimize dart others have found?

Comment: What do you mean by receive polymer elements?

Comment: For example:
<link rel="import" href="your_element.html">

I want to limit as many as these as we can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a "build" out of your project (e.g. generating to js) then all the imports will be replaced with their corresponding HTML Code. And normally .html files will be cached so even if you will create an element more than once, it will be loaded from your server only once.

I would not wonder too much about speed of `<link rel="import">`.

Regards
Robert